# why not always branch(make it default) when we clone in git?

Tags: git

This question might sound weird, let me explain it.

I am learning git recently and I have a question.
I heard that people said when ever you need to add a new feature/bug fix to a repo, you always branch. So later on you can be flexible in production's code roll out and deployment by using merge and rebase. I got this part.

But why would someone not branching the project and adding changes directly to the origin/master? I almost feel like after we clone a repo, we always branch because we got work to be done and we don't want to mess the origin/master up.
So why git not just always make a new branch when we clone?

Comment: Because you don't always branch from `master`. Different teams adopt different flows. I don't think I've even branched from `master` once during my last project as we adopted something similar to the ["gitflow"](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow) style of work.

Comment: In fact, when you clone a repository, git automatically creates a new local branch for you.  The default branch it creates depends on the value stored in `HEAD` in the original repository.  You can specify an alternative branch with `-b` or "no checkout at all" with `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you're describing is one of the workflows possible, not the only one and certainly not the best one for every conceivable situation :)

Let's assume you just want to do a quick-fix on a project, branching and then rebasing / merging back your changes would get in the way of getting the work done.

On the other hand, if you're in it for the long run, branching automatically will only get you a 5s bonus top ? In the long run, it's nothing.